# Return Item's Presentation Details In Rest API programatically

Tags: sitecore

I have a Rest API which needs to return an item's presentation details.
I tried this line of code, but Sitecore.Context.Device is null, since this is a rest API call.

```
LayoutItem layoutItem = item.Visualization.GetLayout(Sitecore.Context.Device);
```

Update: I tried moving this code to when I index my data (hoping to read the value and write it to Solr), but I am facing the same issue.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The renderings are added per "device" in Sitecore, but in most cases nowadays, there's only one device. Depending on how you route your API endpoint etc., the device may not be resolved automatically. If you know you only have one device, you could pick the first device, or provide the device as a parameter. Then you can use a device switcher in case you need to call other Sitecore methods that requires a device to be set. For example like this:

```
var deviceName = "Default"; // The default device. Modify according to needs
var deviceItem = item.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll().First(d => string.Equals(d.Name, deviceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
using (new DeviceSwitcher(deviceItem)) 
{
  ...
}
```